# What is this method doing? (Java)

Tags: java, class

I am completely lost as to what the equals method below is doing. I think it is checking whether or not an object is equal to something but I am confused.

```
public class Point {

    private int x,y;

    public Point(int x, int y){
        x = this.x;
        y = this.y;
    }

    public boolean equals(Point p){ // I am confused by what this method is doing?
        return x == p.x && y == p.y; // What is p.x and p.y doing?
    }

    public int getx(){
        return x;
    }

    public int gety(){
        return y;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return new String("(" + x + ", " + y + ")");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is checking whether two Points have the same content.

The `p.x` is the `x` field of the object referenced by `p`.  This is how you can compare the contents of the current object with the contents of another object.

There is a serious bug here as well.  The normal pattern to use is

```
public boolean equals(Object o) {
```

This is the method generally called and so your method will not be called by most utility classes like HashSet or ArrayList.

Answer (score 1):

The function equals takes an argument, a `Point` object called `p`.

The function then checks if its' current `x` value is equal to the `x` value of the `Point` `p`.
(`x == p.x`)

And also the same for `y`.
(`y == p.y`)

If they are both true, it returns that the two point objects are equal.

(That is, that the current `Point` object is equal to the `Point` `p` that was passed to the function `equals`.)